# CGAL::General_polygon_set_2::join with an iterator of `General_polygon_with_holes_2`s crashes for intersecting shapes

Tags: cgal

## Problem

I have attempted to improve efficiency of one of my functions. To do this I have replaced a loop that sequentially joins `General_polygon_with_holes_2`s to a `General_polygon_set_2`. The replacement is an overload of `General_polygon_set_2::join` that takes iterators.

The specific method in the documentation:

```
template<class InputIterator >
void join (InputIterator begin, InputIterator end)
```

However, this results in a crash whenever any of the input polygons intersects with the polygons in the polygon set. The old code using the single polygon overload of join handles this correctly.

Am I misusing this method? Or is this unintended behavior / a bug to be reported?

## Example

I have experimented with which combinations of polygons produce an error, and which seem to pass uneventfully. It seems to only throw an error for the case where there is some intersection of polygons, whilst the number of polygons in the iterator seems largely irrelevant.

Here is a reduced example with two triangles that crashes on my machine.

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Gps_circle_segment_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/General_polygon_set_2.h>
#include <CGAL/to_rational.h>

#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel   K;
typedef CGAL::Gps_circle_segment_traits_2<K>            T;
typedef T::NT                           NT;
typedef T::Rational_point_2                 Point;
typedef T::X_monotone_curve_2                   C;
typedef T::General_polygon_2                    P;
typedef T::General_polygon_with_holes_2             PWH;
typedef CGAL::General_polygon_set_2<T>              PSet;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Make first polygon.
    const int LEN = 3;
    std::vector<Point> points = { 
        Point(CGAL::to_rational<NT>(1), CGAL::to_rational<NT>(1)),
        Point(CGAL::to_rational<NT>(3), CGAL::to_rational<NT>(1)), 
        Point(CGAL::to_rational<NT>(2), CGAL::to_rational<NT>(3)) 
    };
    C curve;
    P firstBound, secondBound;
    int currI = 0;
    int prevI = LEN - 1;
    while (currI < LEN)
    {
        curve = C(points[prevI], points[currI]);
        firstBound.push_back(curve);
        prevI = currI;
        currI++;
    }
    PWH first, second;
    first.outer_boundary() = firstBound;
    // Make second polygon.
    const int LEN2 = 3;
    std::vector<Point> points2 = { 
        Point(CGAL::to_rational<NT>(2), CGAL::to_rational<NT>(2)),
        Point(CGAL::to_rational<NT>(4), CGAL::to_rational<NT>(2)),
        Point(CGAL::to_rational<NT>(3), CGAL::to_rational<NT>(4)) 
    };
    currI = 0;
    prevI = LEN2 - 1;
    while (currI < LEN2)
    {
        curve = C(points2[prevI], points2[currI]);
        secondBound.push_back(curve);
        prevI = currI;
        currI++;
    }
    // Set up polygon set.
    second.outer_boundary() = secondBound;
    std::vector<PWH> polygons;
    polygons.push_back(second);
    PSet polySet = PSet(first);
    // Program crashes for join.
    polySet.join(polygons.begin(), polygons.end());

    return 0;
}
```

[Diagram of the input triangles from the example code above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VwXC.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce it and just from a brief examination the code seems fine. Which version of CGAL are you using? Which os? Make sure you use polySet.join() and not polySet.insert() when the polygons might not be disjoint (which is the case here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed this issue (or at least worked around it).

There were two separate issues.

### First, compiling templates.

First, I suspect the Visual Studio compiler I have been using wasn't properly distinguishing between the templated functions. Note the third parameter.

```
template <typename InputIterator>
inline void join(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, 
                 Polygon_2&, unsigned int k = 5)
```

```
template <typename InputIterator>
inline void join(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end,
                 Polygon_with_holes_2&, unsigned int k = 5)
```

I am not sure why it couldn't do this, but replacing `join(polygons.begin(), polygons.end())` with `join(polygons.begin(), polygons.end(), General_polygon_with_holes_2())` has stopped the crashes.

### Second, join isn't cleaning up after itself.

The second problem might be a CGAL bug. The iterator based join method isn't un-visiting the underlying arrangement's faces after the process is done.

This causes issues for later method calls because they assume that `face.visited() == false`. E.g. `polySet.polygons_with_holes_2()` won't return any polygons because it assumes all starting faces are unvisited and then visits each face exactly once.

I have circumvented this issue by running the following code after each call to join.

```
for (auto faceIter = arr.faces_begin();
        faceIter != arr.faces_end();
        faceIter++)
    {
        faceIter->set_visited(false);
    }
```